# Querying in Solr

Tags: java, solr

I want to know what are the query classes that Solr use for querying. And what are the difference in querying using lucene and Solr

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking, but SOLR is basically a search/indexing server. It has an external http based api for sending documents to be indexed and to search them.

One of the core pieces of SOLR is Lucene. This is the library that actually indexes/searches stuff.

If you need the API/query info for SOLR (which should mirror very closely that of lucene), look on lucene.apache.org

Answer (score 1):

Solr allows you to have a distributed search engine that is exposed as a web-service to your client application. If you are asking, how to use it on the client side, just look at solrj api. If you ask for internal SOLR apis and classes, then you could start from the QueryComponent class, e.g. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/handler/component/QueryComponent.html.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is the technology used by solr to perform searches.

I'm not 100% what you are asking but if its how do i query solr, then you simply visit or curl a url, the url will contain the solr query. e.g.
price:[0-1000]
or
name:test

the first part (before the :) is the field,and the second part is the search which can be text,numeric range etc...
there is plenty of documentation regarding this on solr's wiki

Let me know what your actual problem is and ill gladly help